# Finding a prime numbers between 1 - 239 using embedded loop

Tags: c++, loops

I am unable to figure out how to find all of the prime numbers between 1 and 239 using an embedded loop.    Here is the code I have so far I know I am on the right track but I do not know where to go from here as this is not returning the right output

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{


int n, x, y, is_prime;

n = 0;
while (n < 239)
{
  n++;
  is_prime=1;
   x=2; 
  while (x < n)
     {
     y = n % x;
     if (y == 0)
     {is_prime = 0;
     x = n;}
     else x++;
     }

if (is_prime = 1)
cout << n;
cout << endl;  
}
system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Quick note, the smallest number a non-prime can be divided by is half of itself. So you only have to check up to 239/2 rounded downwards. I would also place it in a function and let it return true if it is a prime and false if not. That way you can "break" the while-loop if it finds that it is a non-prime.

Comment: `if (is_prime = 1)` probably doesn't do what you want, use `==`, and put braces around the two statements after the if unless you want 239 newlines to print.

Comment: As a correction to @Emz, you only need to check to ceil(sqrt(n)), not n/2. This cuts way down on your checks.

Comment: @RetiredNinja thanks man I realize now why that wasn't working

Comment: To find a list of primes up to a number, use [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). To check if a number n is prime or not, just checking up to sqrt(n) is enough, and you don't even need to check for even divisors. Moreover just need to check divisors in the form 6k ± 1. You way is very slow

Comment: @Emz I don't really understand what you're saying.  I'm good at math but don't know what you mean rounded downwards or placing it in a function.  As I said earlier my teacher is horrible and does not really explain things as well as he should.  I have a 100 in the class and honestly feel like I have learned nothing.

Comment: Sorry @LưuVĩnhPhúc I don't know anything about that.  I hope I am not supposed to know that only 2 months into a Junior College course.  Making my head hurt lol

Comment: @user1543042 yes, sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.  Here's some working code, but if this is for an assignment, try to work it out yourself, and just peek at the answer if you're stuck.

```
      #include <iostream>
      using namespace std;

      bool isPrime(int n){
        //first check if n equals 2 or n is divisible by 2
        if (n == 2) return 1;
        if (n%2 == 0) return 0;
        //start at 3, only check the odds, and stop at square root of n
        for (int i = 3; i * i <= n; i+=2){
         if (n%i == 0)
           return 0;
        }
        return 1;
      }

      int main()
      {
        //2 is the only even prime number
        cout << 2 << " ";
        //now the rest are odds
        for (int i = 3; i <= 239; i+=2){
          if (isPrime(i)){
           //print i if it is a prime number
           cout << i << " ";
          }
        } 
        cout << endl;                     
      }
```

Output:

> 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
>   101 103 107 109 113 127 131 137 139 149 151 157 163 167 173 179 181
>   191 193 197 199 211 223 227 229 233 239

Ultra-simplified:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    cout << 2 << " ";

    int prime = 1;
    for (int i = 3; i <= 239; i+=2){
      for (int j = 3; j * j <= i; j+=2){
         if (i%j == 0){
           prime = 0;
           break;
         }
      }

      if (prime == 1){
        cout << i << " ";
      }
      prime = 1;

    }
    cout << endl;                     
  }
```

Comment: I haven't learned bool or how to use whatever funtion isPrime() is or return or any of that.  The class I am taking is absolutely horrible.  Also your output left out 1 :) 

Thank you for your help though.

Comment: @Taylor Clark, 1 is not a prime number!  http://primes.utm.edu/lists/small/1000.txt       http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number

Comment: Haha.  Man I've got a lot of learning to do.  I appreciate it man.  Should I already know all of that stuff if I am just now learning while and for loops and using switch.  We haven't really done anything with bool or anything like that yet either.

Comment: It's just cleaner to put it in a separate function.  It's basically a nested loop, or embedded loop as you put it, but the inner loop is in the `isPrime ()` function.

Comment: Dang man any recommendations for learning from scratch? Or will I learn that kind of thing as I get more into c++

Comment: @Taylor Clark sorry to hear about the bad teacher.  If you're interested in programming, just keep at it!  I just added a simplified version that doesn't use bool, and doesn't use a separate function.